# Having a servlet to setup the WebApplication

Tags: java, servlets

In my web application I have two servlets which act as a controller. One servlet is used to handle web requests and another servlet is used to handle AJAX requests.

```
//This servlet manages web requests, and forwards to JSP to display data
WebController extends HttpServlet: 

// This servlet manages AJAX requests. And returns JSON to user
AJAXController extends HttpServlet: This servlet manages
```

In my `web.xml` I have the following mapping defined:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>WebController</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.frontend.WebController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>WebController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>

  <servlet-name>AJAXController</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.AJAXController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AJAXController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So you can see I load `WebController` before `AJAXController`.
In the `init()` method of `webController`, I do all the initialization tasks.

```
loading the database driver
initializing the configuration
and other stuff that I need for my web application
```

The load-on-startup makes sure that before any AJAX request come to the server, the web app is initialized and I can be sure to make database access.

However, I do not like the idea of initializing web application in one servlet. I am thinking of having a separate servlet called `InitServlet` and move the code from `WebController`'s init method to `InitServlet`'s `init()` method

### Questions

1. Is it a good idea? Are there other approaches to solve this problem?
2. What should my servlet-mapping look like given that init servlet's sole purpose is to initialize the web application and as such it should not be mapped to any URL

I will send `HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN` in their `doPost()` and `doGet()` method. But if possible I want ths servlet not to be mapped to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better idea to move your initialize code to [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

When your app starts it will execute `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` and you'll get a chance to init everything.

And [this](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/) is how you hook it to your web.xml

Comment: This doesn't answer his question as he has two servlets and he doesn't want to initialize the context in one servlet.

Comment: @CBass the point is to move the init code away from the servlets.

Comment: Yes, but not his question. His question was about whether using a third servlet that gets loaded first would work. And of course it does.

Comment: I think both the approaches will work ... but I like using ServletContextListener better than having a special servlet to just do this ...

Comment: I also have some cleanup code which I can hook up in ServletContetextListener's context destroyed

Comment: @CBass but having a Do Nothing servlet that only has an init() clause is no longer necessary, nor is it really the appropriate place for this kind of initialization. The SessionContextListener is the more appropriate place for this kind of code since it is tied to the lifecycle of the application, and not the life cycle of the servlets (which are different from the application). Using an "init-only" made sense back in the year 2000, but we've had ServletContextListener since 2001. Better to update to the better mechanisms for this.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not necessarily a bad idea. Just define your initialization server to load first in the web.xml. As far as the entry goes, it needs to define the servlet class, of course and the load on startup order.

Put your initialization code in an implemented init method. Leave the doGet doPost methods empty so if they get called nothing happens. The init method will only get called once when the servlet is loaded.

The only issues I see is if this is being run into the context of a clustered set of application servers and you have resources that are truly singleton (like a connection pool), but in that case you can initialize these through application configuration in the application server. They will get intialized when the application starts and before the servlets are loaded.